# How to save data in temp table from my query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query. I want to save result in my Temp Table and  `isWithInCircle` value in variable also, how do this?

```
declare @source geography = geography::Point(30.221101852485987, 71.575927734375, 4326), @target geography = geography::Point(29.9358952133724, 71.817626953125, 4326);

declare @radius_in_miles int = 100; 

declare @radius_in_meters float = @radius_in_miles * 1081.7316;

select @target.STBuffer(@radius_in_meters).STContains(@source) AS [isWithinCircle],
 @target.STDistance(@source) AS [distance_in_meters],
 @target.STBuffer(@radius_in_meters).STDisjoint(@source) AS [isPastCircle];
```

Comment: Why have you tagged 3 different versions of SQL Server?

Comment: i think this helps others developers

Comment: No it doesn't, what matters is what version you are using. If you want it to be version agnostic, then don't tag a specific version. How about v2014 or v2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my limited understanding of what you are trying to do, but this should work...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #MyTempTable;

declare @source geography = geography::Point(30.221101852485987, 71.575927734375, 4326), @target geography = geography::Point(29.9358952133724, 71.817626953125, 4326);

declare @radius_in_miles int = 100; 

declare @radius_in_meters float = @radius_in_miles * 1081.7316;

declare @isWithinCircle int;

select @target.STBuffer(@radius_in_meters).STContains(@source) AS [isWithinCircle],
 @target.STDistance(@source) AS [distance_in_meters],
 @target.STBuffer(@radius_in_meters).STDisjoint(@source) AS [isPastCircle]
 into #MyTempTable;

 select @isWithinCircle = isWithinCircle from #MyTempTable

 select @isWithinCircle
```

Comment: Thanks Dear Your Great :)